# What is reference north for DJI Onboard SDK (Magnetic or True)

Tags: dji-sdk

The onboard SDK has several parameters that are referenced to North but the documentation does not indicate which North (true or magnetic).  I'm particularly interested in the acceleration relative to ground, since that's measured with accelerometers - is the magnetic variation removed from that number prior to being reported?  Also, the reported YAW angle...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

DJI software uses magnetic north. Any reference to true north in the docs I assume to mean "true" magnetic north.

Questions about accelerometer yaw calculation are not relevent to the compass as far as I know.